# javascript fetch return s3 response in json

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-s3

I am fetching a s3 url like:

```
fetch(url, {method: 'PUT', data: data}).then(response => { return response.json()})
```

When I do `response.json()` it gives me error.

It gives me response like:

```
<CompleteMultipartUploadResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Location>http://mule-uploader-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/479564</Location><Bucket>mule-uploader-demo</Bucket><Key>479564</Key><ETag>&quot;42c3b5ebe4637e018604b3f1965a2c89-9&quot;</ETag></CompleteMultipartUploadResult>
```

How can I covert response to json ??

Answer (score 0):

recommend use this package to convert XML to JSON as you request here,
https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

use it as exampled here: http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gkxucxrj/1/

`x2js.xml_str2json("<YOUR XML>")`

good luck